# How can I copy CTRL-C content from a single cell in DBISQL?

Tags: sa

I use DBISQL on Win32 on 12.0.1.3769.

Usually, I am interested in copying cell content from the Result pane of DBISQL, not the contents of the complete row or the row headers.

I can do this by using the context menu and choose "copy data / cell" (I use a localised version, the English words may be different). But I would certainly like to use CTRL-C to copy only the contents of selected cells. As stated, however, CTRL-C copies the full row(s) including the header of the column. And all too often I try to insert a single number in a particular window, then insert an entire database unintentionally instead...

**Question:** **Can I use another shortcut or is there a choice in the result pane to change the meaning of CTRL-C?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Ctrl-C maps to Copy Data Rows effectively, while you (and I!!!) would like to MALL map it to Copy Data-Columns, as defined here: copying columns, rows and cells in an Interactive SQL result collection.

The complete list of [Interactive SQL Keyboard Shortcuts dates](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/isql-keyboard-shortcuts.html) back to 1985... However, even then, cool children's software allows you to change the key tasks (hint, hint:)

Thank you, Volker, for noting how Really Annoying Ctrl-C is [ end sarcasm alert ] ... [ sarcasm alert ] Until now it had been only one of the little irritants of your life such as an alarm that went away before you finished sleeping.